# Selected Listview item giving a null object reference error

Tags: android, listview, null

Currently I'm working with a list view, the list view holds three values, ID,Title and Description.

Here is the XML for the list view..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Ln"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoteID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.39"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Pub" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="PubTest" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The list is populated with data from a database, and everything works up until this point. However I do need to be able to delete items from the database, I figured having a context menu when an item is clicked would be easiest as the user could select the item to be deleted. However i'm getting this error

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null
>   object reference"

This is the context menu delete code...

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo Info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.DeleteItem: {
            DB = new DBController(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete("NOTES", "ID=" + NoteID.getText().toString(), null);
            Toast.makeText(StoredNoteList.this, "deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I'm fairly certain that the issue is with the NoteID.getText().toString()- My theory is that when I select something from the list, the item ID selected Isn't saved in the NoteID Variable, this is just a theory though.

For those who asked for the NoteID
Declaring and assigning the NoteID

```
TextView NoteID,NoteTitle,NoteDesc;
NoteID=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNoteID);
```

After making some changes I now see that my NoteID is definitely null

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo Info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        NoteList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ID =((TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.txtNoteID)).getText().toString();
            }
        });
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.DeleteItem:
            {
                DB = new DBController(getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = DB.getWritableDatabase();
                db.delete("NOTES", "ID=" + ID, null);
                Toast.makeText(StoredNoteList.this,"deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
```

The Debugger shows me NoteID is null, I think once I find a way to store the selected id from the itemlist into the NoteID variable, my app should work with no problems.

Here is my adapter code for any who are interested

```
    Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(StoredNoteList.this, Data, R.layout.rows,new String[]{"ID","TITLE","DESCRIPTION"}, new int[]{R.id.txtNoteID,R.id.txtTitle,R.id.txtDesc});
NoteList.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code where variable ``NoteID`` is created? Full stack trace would be helpful too.

Comment: Please note that variables should start with lowercase letters. It's a Java coding convention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a custom adapter? I think your issue is that it doesn't know WHICH NoteID to get. There are effectively a bunch of elements with the txtNoteID because of the ListView. So you would want to do something along the lines of:

```
    NoteList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ID = view.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

The view in the onItemClick should be the correct view, you may need to grab parent and do a lookup for the txtNoteID within the context of that listView item though so...

```
 ((TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.txtNoteID)).getText().toString()
```

Comment: I've added my adapter code if you'd like to take a look at it. I do understand what you mean by it not knowing which NoteID to use, I did think that the ItemClickListener only worked with the selected item so i didn't think this would be an issue. Where exactly should i put the second line of code you posted ? I am alittle lost on that one

Comment: ID = view.getText().toString(); would be replaced by that second line of code. ID =((TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.txtNoteID)).getText().toString() based on the adapter code, I would say use the second line of code in lieu of the first one. It should work for you then.

Comment: To be clear ...... ``NoteList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ID =((TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.txtNoteID)).getText().toString();
            }
        });``  This however is still giving me a null value

Comment: Hm... that should of worked. Try view.findViewById...  One of those two things should work either on the parent or the view itself... Put a break point and take a look at the children in the view and parent and find which has it. Sorry I can't help you more explicitly.  You also have the position so you can always find it in the list as well and pull it out that way, but scrolling lists can sometimes obscure that.

Comment: I have updated the question to show my updated code, Could it be possible I have put your code in the wrong spot ?

Comment: I've put a breakpoint on the setOnItemClick listener and when clicking an item in the listview the breakpoint doesn't even respond, could it be possible that the onItemClick listener isn't the correct method to use ?

Comment: Are you sure public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) is being entered into? I'm thinking nothing is being "hooked" up so to speak because it's not being called.

Comment: Yes it is being entered because when i choose delete it runs the code and displays the toast, but with the ID being empty the code doesn't work. However the setOnItemClickListener isn't being entered at all. I was wondering if this may be in the wrong place ?

Comment: Try moving that part into your onCreate or onResume of the Activity.

Comment: Adding it to the onCreate did solve the problem, however i am now sitting with a different one. The first two items deleted fine but when it came to items with the id of 4 , 5 ,6. I still had the null error. When selecting ID number 6 it sometimes returns ID as 3

Comment: So I've had this happen as well... basically what happens is the list isn't repopulated with the new "values" from the database. This coupled with the fact that when scrolling through the positions remain static so everything on the page is the same number regardless of what page you're on. The best way I've found to fix this is to not use the simple adapter and implement a custom list adapter